# How to change selector background color without filling options background colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i change background color of my select, its appear to all options. But i want to get `UI` as follows. How to change background color only selector area.

`Jquery` when page is load.

```
$("#age1").css("background-color", "#fe5a5f");
```

[image]

```
<select id="age1">
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21" selected="">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: You will probably want to find another solution for Mac OS users, I don't believe the default dropdown behaviour will be affected by the colour here. Complete custom Jquery selects are best for this sort of job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another css for options options with white background and selector area will not be effected with that

```
$("#age1").css("background-color", "#fe5a5f"); 
$("#age1 option").css("background-color", "transparent");
```

Selector area will be colored and options will be transparent background

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/owgpsf7a/

Answer (score 1):

please try this..I have made a small editting to Gurav aggarwals fiddle
   https://jsfiddle.net/owgpsf7a/1/

```
<select id="age1">
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21" selected="">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option> 
</select>
```

css

```
#age1{
  background-color:green;
}
#age1 option{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

jquery

```
$("#age1").css("background-color", "green"); 
$("#age1 option").css("background-color", "transparent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
.pink {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#color_me").change(function(){
    var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
    $("#color_me").attr("class", color);
});
```

HTML

```
*<select id="color_me" class="">
    <option class="green">successful</option>
    <option class="orange">process failure</option>
    <option class="pink">abandoned</option>
</select>*
```